# How to directly redirect to 404 error page when enter the wrong url in prestashop 1.7?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Currently when i enter the wrong url for example **https://www.example.com/1234** then it redirect to 302 and then redirect to 404 page.

I need to directly redirect to 404 error page for SEO purpose.

I have also tried with below solution in htaccess.

## If rewrite mod isn't enabled

> ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?controller=404

Please help me with solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try in your backoffice :

Shop parameters -> Traffic & SEO

In block -> Set up URLs

Redirect to the canonical URL : 301 Moved Permantly

[image]

Comment: Clear cache and change navigator ?

Comment: Friendly URL and Accented URL is enable, should it caused ?